# Criteria for the maximum of $f(x) = axe^{bx}$ at $(2,1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

I have this question and have been trying for a long time to fully solve it, hopefully you guys can help me. Here is the question:

> Consider the function $f(x) = axe^{bx}$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants and real numbers. Find the possible value(s) of $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x)$ has an absolute maximum of $(2, 1)$ on the interval $[0, 50]$. Give your answer in exact form.

I got one answer, but can't seem to prove or find out other possible answers. Here is my solution for one possible answer:

$f(x) = axe^{bx}$

- $1=f(2) =2ae^{2b}$

  $ae^{2b}=\frac12$
- $f'(x) = ae^{bx}(1+xb)$

  $0=f'(2) = ae^{2b}(1+2b)=\frac12(1+2b)$

  $b = -\frac12$

$ae^{2(-1/2)}=\frac12$

$a =\frac e2$.

So one of my possible answers is $a=\frac e2$ and $b=-\frac12$.
Now my only problem is the question asked for the possible value(s), so I don't know if there is more than one possible answer. Then question did specify on the interval from $[0,50]$. So I don't know if there is a function that is greater in the negative, but has a maximum on the interval $[0,50]$ on the positive end, or sort of a U-shaped function where it has a maximum at $(2,1)$ goes below, but then possible goes back up after $x=50$, which would still satisfy the criteria.

Just looking for some help if I got the only answer, or if there are more answers.

*Note: the question did say that $a$ and $b$ are constants and real numbers.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please use [math jax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typing your formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Questions that say something along the lines of "possible value(s)" actually mean: "find the one possible value of $a$ and $b$ or if multiple values work list all of them". This is worded like that so that the question doesn't hint on how many answers you should get, it's vague on purpose!

The work you provided is indeed correct and indeed, there is only one possible combination of values for $a$ and $b$, namely as you mentioned:
\begin{align}
a= \dfrac{e}{2} && \text{and}&& b=-\dfrac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much, I was definitely scared about the wording of "possible value(s)" and currently think that the solution I got is the only one justifiable. I still have some doubt about the question specifying on the interval [0,50]. So how would I justify that this is the only possible answer, as from my solution. I can only vaguely explain why this solution is the only one possible for the functions entire domain, not specifically on the specified interval.

Answer (score 0):

Your own calculation
$$f'(x)=ae^{bx}(1+xb)$$
shows that *$f$ has a unique critical point* (except of course if $a=0$ or $b=0$, in which case $f$ is constant). So, the answer to your question about the possibility of more complicated shapes for the graph of $f$ is: no.

Moreover, this critical point is an absolute extremum on $\Bbb R$ and is at
$$\left(-\frac1b,-\frac abe^{-1}\right)=(2,1)$$
iff $b=-\frac12$ and $a=-eb=\frac e2$, as you found. (It is then *de facto* also an absolute extremum on any interval containing $2$.)

The only thing you forgot to check, to make sure that this unique possible solution is indeed a solution (i.e. that there is one solution and not zero), is that this extremum is a maximum. You can check more generally that if $ab<0$ then the extremum of $f$ at $x=-1/b$ is a maximum, by looking at the sign of $f'(x)=abe^{bx}(x+1/b)$ when $x<-1/b$ and when $x>-1/b$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your last point that I forgot to check to make sure that this unique possible solution is indeed a solution, I am a bit confused on what you mean and hoping you can explain it to me as the question does require me to justify the values I found are the only possible values.

Comment: You proved that $f$ (restricted to $[0,50]$) has an absolute extremum at  $(2,1)$ iff $(a,b)=(e/2,-1/2)$, but since  the question asked for a maximum, you must check that if  $(a,b)=(e/2,-1/2)$, this extremum $(2,1)$ is a maximum and not a minimum. I edited the last sentence of my answer for more detail.

Comment: Oh ok, so I'm guessing I could use the second derivative test to check if it is positive or negative and then it will tell me if it is concave up or down which will tell me if it is a maximum or a minimum.

Comment: You could indeed, but looking at the sign of the first derivative (as described at the end of my answer) is more elementary.

Answer (score 0):

By differentiation (ProductRule, simplification) it is found
$$(x_m,y_m)=(-1/b,-a/(be))$$
when equated to $(2,1)$ we obtain
$$ (a,b)= (e/2, -\frac12)$$
Second derivative sign test shows max at this choice.

Your work is correct and it appears to me that there need not be any doubt . If a second value is admissible, it will surely come out here as a double or multiple root.

Confirmed by function graph also:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, you talked about the possibility of a double or multiple root. Would you have any idea to check whether an answer like this even exist, and if an answer does, how I would be able to solve it.

Comment: f'(x)=0 supplies all solutions. If a polynomial, we check the degree. Graphically, location of points with zero slope.